# Angular Digest Timer

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to figure out the time it takes for the digest cycle to run, so I've written something like this:

```
mPulseApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var d = new Date();
    var $digest = $rootScope.$digest;
    var $newDigest = function () {
        var time = d.getTime();
        $digest.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('time:' + (d.getTime() - time));
    }
    $rootScope.$digest = $newDigest;
}]);
```

This runs however the times are always the same, as if the $digest.apply method is running async. Note that I'm on a pretty heavy page when I test this and should notice some amount of time.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just curious, since you don't have arguments defined, shouldn't the call to $digest be $digest() - not $digest.apply(this, arguments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store your date/time

```
var d = new Date();
```

You've set d equal to the date/time of when that line executed. Calling d.getTime() returns the time component of that object, so you can hold onto that object for an hour and d.getTime() will return the same result. You can test this behavior in your browser's console.

If you're using Chrome, try using the performance.now() method to obtain a high precision timestamp that you can use to calculate performance. For example:

```
PulseApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {

    var $digest = $rootScope.$digest;
    var $newDigest = function () {
        var d = performance.now();
        $digest.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('time:' + (performance.now() - d) + ' ms');
    }
    $rootScope.$digest = $newDigest;
}]);
```

Subtracting the two performance.now() calls gives you, in milliseconds, the execution time. See [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now%28%29) for more info related to performance.now()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mPulseApp.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var $digest = $rootScope.$digest;
    var $newDigest = function () {
        var time1 = new Date().getTime();
        $digest.apply(this, arguments);
        var time2 = new Date().getTime();
        console.log('time:' + (time2 - time1));
    }
    $rootScope.$digest = $newDigest;
}]);
```